# using Push to add to array, but array is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to process the selected files and add a new file to an array which will be used later. But even though Src contains 14 elements my Files array are always empty.

```
const tap = require("gulp-tap");
const vinyl = require("vinyl");
var files = [];

const getFilename = src => {
.........
}

const getContent = src => "@import \"" + src.toString().replace(".scss", "") + "\"";

return src(path + "/**/*.scss")
.pipe(tap((file, t) => {
    files.push(new vinyl({
        base: "./",
        filename: getFilename(file),
        contents: Buffer.from(getContent(file))
    }));
}));
```

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wan%27t

Comment: did you `console.log` your vinyl objects?

Comment: what the person above me said. are you sure a vinyl object is being created? are you sure the files.push() function is being executed? try pushing in random numbers, is the array still turning up empty?

Comment: @dar no I'm not sure. but  I've found another way to process the files so I'm not using this code anymore

Comment: Judging by the fact that the files array is a top level variable, I'm guessing that you're looking at the `files` array BEFORE the `files.push()` has actually run.  Put a couple of unique `console.log()` statements right after you do the `.push()` and right before you look at the results of the array (at the place where you say it's empty).  You'll probably see you are looking at the array before the `.pipe()` completion callback has been called.  So, this would be an asynchronous timing issue.  Show us more of your code if you want more specific help with a solution.